# Where should I store JWT token?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, vuex

I'm developing an app using vue.js and vuex which authenticates to a JSON API server using JWT tokens. 
So I'm wondering what is the best practice to store JWT token?

If I store it in vuex store, it gets lost after the page refresh, so user needs to login again, which is not very convenient.

And if I store it in the browser's localstorage, It gets deprecated before the next login and then components which assume the authentication token get confused. I have no idea how to deal with this.

Appreciate your hints on this.

Comment: use a cookie, it fits with your problem

Comment: You can use localStorage

Comment: @PareshGami I explained what's the problem with localStorage.

Comment: You have to check token while use going again on site

Comment: You can store it in a cookie.

Comment: Here is a great article from dev.to with some meaningful external resources which will help you make your choice between cookies and localStorage: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: What is your authorization server? Is it the API one or another, like google or facebook?

Comment: @sawim The backend is in node.js

Answer (score 2):

Below is a snapshot from my react project with axios library, where I had a similar problem. When response from server was 401 (Unauthenticated), I requested for a new JWT token using another token (refreshToken) with no expiration date

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    ok => ok,
    err => {
        if(err.response.status === 401) {
            return axios
                    .get('/api/oauth/token/refresh', {
                        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') }`}
                    })
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        // in data is new access token
                        err.config.headers['Authorization']=`Bearer ${data.token}`;
                        return axios(err.config)
                    });

        } 

        throw err
    }
);
```

Comment: What's the benefit? If you can refresh it anytime, why let it expire?

Answer (score 1):

> And if I store it in the browser's localstorage, It gets deprecated
>   before the next login and then components which assume the
>   authentication token get confused. I have no idea how to deal with
>   this.

This is not true, localStorage information is saved per Document origin.
It the application responsibility to check if the token is still available(not expired) and if not redirect him to the Login page.

You should extend you expiration to how long is reasonable to relogin, and you should think of a decent algorithm to extend his JWT token. e.g Every time a user is doing a request to the server and is left with 1hr you can increase is login for 1day.